# How to show the right hand side layout/margin?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I used to have the margin highlighted below. How can I display it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by showing the margin, you mean showing the vertical colored annotations on the scroll bar, they can be enabled by going into **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C#** > **Scroll Bars** and then enabling required annotations in the **Display** group

[image]

If you meant highlighting the background of the annotation area, then you must select **Use map mode for vertical scroll bar** under the **Behavior** group and set the desired width from the **Source overview** drop-down

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to set "Map Mode" for the vertical scroll bar. This is a language-dependent, text-editor setting: for C#, select the "Options" command from the "Tools" menu; open the "Text Editor" and "C#" nodes of the tree in the left-hand pane and select "Scroll Bars." Then, in the right-hand pane, select the "Use map mode for vertical scroll bar" radio-button (there are several options as to how much detail you want to show in the scroll bar; the image you posted suggests using the "Off" option from the "Source overview" drop-down combo).

Here's a screen-shot:

[image]

The process is similar for other supported languages, such as Basic, F# and 'C/C++'. Also, be sure to actually *enable* the vertical scroll bar (check-box near the top of the same pane).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for *show vertical scroll bar* option, and the checkbox on top of your screenshot did the trick.. If I use the *Map Mode* I get the *Preview Tooltip* which is a different bar, so I guess this might confuse the future readers.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini The "Preview Tooltip" checkbox is something of a red herring: that merely enables pop-up help "bubbles" when actually hovering in the side pane. However, you need *both* the options I've mentioned to get the display you indicated: "Show vertical scroll bar" ***and*** "Use map mode...".

Comment: erm, I tried them both, but when I use *Map Mode* I get the overview scroll bar which is wider than the *vertical scroll bar*. Thanks though, your screenshot solved my problem.